# Android layout weight doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I got this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6sp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:inputType="none" />

    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title" 
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<!-- android:id="@android:id/widget_frame" -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/change_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip" >

    </SeekBar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text_Box_seek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:textSize="16dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the seek bar to take 80% of the width in the inner linear layout, but the seek bar stays very small.. why won't it take the rest of the space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the layout width of your `LinearLayout` to match_parent or set a specific value for it.

**Explain**
If you use LinearLayout width = wrap_content, the width of LinearLayout will depend of the childs.
And you also set the weight for the childs, so the the width of the child will depend on the parent.
=> (width of parent depend on childs, width of childs depend on parent) then I think the View will don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Try including the rest of 20% weight in the `TextView`- `Text_Box_seek`

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text_Box_seek"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:textSize="16dip" >
    </TextView>
```

For distributing weight perfectly, you have to assign weight to all the items according to what you need. Setting others to wrap_content will let them take space neglecting the weight given by you.

**EDIT**

Also as Phan Van Linh answered the width should be match_`parent` or any specified so that the layout does not dpened on its content for its width(which will affect weight distribution.

Answer (score 0):

when you using orientation :Horizontal..at that time layout_width should be 0dp  android:layout_width="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<!-- android:id="@android:id/widget_frame" -->
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="6sp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
  android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
  android:layout_marginTop="6sp">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
<!-- android:id="@android:id/widget_frame" -->

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="6sp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
  android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/change_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:paddingRight="20dip">

  </SeekBar>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text_Box_seek"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:textSize="16dip"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of the LinearLayout to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

just try to set your linear layout property as `android:layout_width="match_parent"`,then layout weight will work.
hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ani and Shreya Patel both right ,just change layout_midth to match_parent in your LinearLayout and the weight will work.